# Не знаю как сделать износ металла на ребрах 3д обьекта в blender 4

Tags: 3d, blender

Мой проект, нужно сделать износ ребер на каркасе(красный каркас).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это аналог, какой результат должен получиться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: блендером никогда не пользовался и вообще далёк от дизайна, но попробуйте как-нибудь выделить эти самые рёбра и перемешать цвета